# Integral of rational function $\int\frac{x^2-18x-1}{(x-1)^2(x^2+1)} \text{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> Evaluate
>   $$\int\dfrac{x^2-18x-1}{(x-1)^2(x^2+1)} \text{d}x$$
>   *(Remember to use $\ln |u|$ where appropriate. Use $\text{C}$ for the constant of integration.)*

I got the answer
$$\dfrac{-1}{2 \ln(x^2+1)} + \dfrac{9}{x+1+\ln|x-1|}+9\tan^{-1}(x) + \text{C}.$$
Is this correct?

Thanks everyone for the help i got the answer!

Comment: Why not take the derivative of the answer you got and see if it matches with the expression in the problem statement?

Comment: You can use http://wolframalpha.com to check

Comment: Shouldn't you use absolute values in the logarithms?

Comment: This is currently not right.

Comment: @AndréNicolas people keep changing the answer, could you care to explain why it's incorrect?

Comment: The Alpha answer linked to by Adriano is right, sort of, though it should really use $\log(|x-1|)$. Your current answer is not equivalent to that one. After the partial fractions process, the integrations are easy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Yes, it's correct.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Cint%5Cfrac%7Bx%5E2-18x-1%7D%7B%28x-1%29%5E2%28x%5E2%2B1%29%7D%20dx) Just don't forget the absolute values (replace $\ln(x - 1)$ with $\ln|x - 1|$).

Comment: okay so for the final answer i should replace those parenthesis with brackets? im putting this into web assign, so i wanna make sure i put in the correct answer.

Comment: @jackthompson As a side note, no need to replace $\ln(x^2+1)$ by $\ln|x+1|$ since $x^2+1$ always gives positive value for real $x$.